# Where to place xs:unique constraint in XSD?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xsd-validation

I am using XSD for XML validation.   I want to add unique values constraint for the `input` elements.

I have XML format like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <definitions>
    <input>Page</input>
  </definitions>
  <definitions>
    <input>Page</input>
  </definitions>
</test>
```

My XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="definitions" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="input"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I want to know how `xs:unique` should be placed.

Comment: What do you mean with "_how unique tag be placed_"? Furthermore, I don't see any attribute in here.

Comment: I am asking how <xs:unique></xsunique> tag to be placed for input tags, as i am not aware of this

Comment: It is still not clear on what you want to be unique.

Comment: I am sorry, I would reframe my question,  Iwant value of the <input> tag to be unqiue. As in my xml, "Page" value is duplicated. SO I want to add unique constraint for <input>

Answer (score 2):

To place the `xs:unique` element:

1. Identify the scope of uniqueness (**`test`**) for the elements of
   `xs:unique/@selector` (**`definitions`**).
2. Place the `xs:unique` element

   - *within* the declaration of **`test`**, and
   - *after* the `xs:complexType` for **`test`**

See **HERE** in the XSD below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="definitions"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="input"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- HERE -->
    <xs:unique name="definitions-input-unique">
      <xs:selector xpath="definitions"/>
      <xs:field xpath="input"/>
    </xs:unique>

  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then this **invalid** XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <definitions>
    <input>Page</input>
  </definitions>
  <definitions>
    <input>Page</input>
  </definitions>
</test>
```

will receive an **error message** such as the following:

> [Error] try.xml:7:24: cvc-identity-constraint.4.1: Duplicate unique
>   value [Page] declared for identity constraint
>   "definitions-input-unique" of element "test".

Answer (score 0):

Just put it at the top level like this:

```html
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
 <xs:element name="test">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="definitions" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element type="xs:string" name="input"/>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:unique name="input-values">
   <xs:selector xpath="./definitions"/>
   <xs:field xpath="input"/>
  </xs:unique>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```